# Realm Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS RLMUtil.hpp RLMIsObjectSubclass

Tags: firebase, crash, realm

I use Realm to cache data. It was behaving normally before but when I use Firebase to monitor app performance, Realm crashes often.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

0   libobjc.A.dylib class_getSuperclass + 4
1   ChopeDashboard  RLMUtil.hpp line 72 RLMIsObjectSubclass + 72
2   ChopeDashboard  RLMSchema.mm line 105 RLMRegisterClassLocalNames(objc_class**, unsigned long) + 105
3   ChopeDashboard  memory line 2942 +[RLMSchema sharedSchema] + 2942
4   ChopeDashboard  RLMRealm.mm line 492 +[RLMRealm realmWithConfiguration:error:] + 492
5   ChopeDashboard  RLMRealm.mm line 190 +[RLMRealm defaultRealm] + 190
6   ChopeDashboard  RLMObject.mm line 141 +[RLMObject objectsWithPredicate:] + 141
7   ChopeDashboard  CDRealmToBookingTool.m line 34 +[CDRealmToBookingTool getOperatingTimesFromDBWithDate:] + 34
8   ChopeDashboard  CDFloorPlanViewController.m line 1031 -[CDFloorPlanViewController setupSessionByStoreWithStartTime:] + 1031
9   ChopeDashboard  CDFloorPlanViewController.m line 1810 -[CDFloorPlanViewController updateFloorPlanAccordingStartTime:endTime:isShowLoading:] + 1810
10  ChopeDashboard  CDFloorPlanViewController.m line 602 -[CDFloorPlanViewController selectNow] + 602
11  ChopeDashboard  CDFloorPlanViewController.m line 240 -[CDFloorPlanViewController viewDidAppear:] + 240
```

I found the same issue in github/Realm. Someone said they faced the same problem about Firebase/performance. But the issue is still open.

Comment: We are using Realm and Firebase with no issues. Posting a crash log is fine but we would need to see the code that caused the crash. Add a breakpoint and step through the code line by line until it crashes and include that code, and the line that crashed in the question. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Jay would you be able provide the version numbers of the FirebasePerformance and Realm libraries that you are using without issues please? For info this issue is also reported on the Realm repo [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5618)